# Insufficient privileges on oracle 8i while LOCK TABLE command

Tags: oracle, locking, oracle8i

I have a package in which I need to put a lock on a table.

I am using the below statement at the beginning of main proc.

```
PROCEDURE proc_main IS
BEGIN

-- added by praphul to test locking 

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'LOCK TABLE schema.XYZ IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT';
```

Getting following error :

```
SQL> exec ssss.abcd.proc_main();
BEGIN ssss.abcd.proc_main(); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: ERROR OCCURED AT STEP:500
REASON: abcd FAILED
SQLCODE: -1031
SYS-MSG: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "ssss.PROC_ERROR_RAISE", line 31
ORA-06512: at "ssss.abcd", line 156
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To successfully lock a table it must be in the same schema you're logged in to, or you must have the LOCK ANY TABLE privilege, or you must be granted any object privilege on the table in question. Apparently the `ssss` user hasn't been granted the appropriate privilege(s) on `schema.XYZ`. Talk to you DBA about this.

Best of luck.

Comment: DBA gave system privileges to me

Comment: And did that fix your problem?

Comment: Then the DBA didn't give you the privilege you need. You need the `LOCK ANY TABLE` privilege. See if your DBA can grant that to you. In addition, check to see if you can SELECT data from this table. Best of luck.